# How to use different assets with same name using multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build an app with multiple targets, each should have different asset versions. The business requirement is to have the same app but with different branding assets. I don't want to copy and paste the project and change icons manually because this won't be efficient.

> As an example, I have a `logo` in the assets catalog, both **Target X** and **Target Y** need to see the asset, but both targets need to see a different version of the asset.

Comment: assets now allow using the same name but a different target. So you need to use a different name for respective target.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by creating additional **Asset Catalogs**, these can be named accordingly, they will need to be added to your required target, **Target Membership**.

[image]

[image]

Having different collections you are able to have the same asset names and the targets will work as expected.

Comment: This is cool but I have several assets that are shared between targets and I would not want to duplicate them acroll all catalogues. Can I have an additional "shared" catalogue too?

Comment: You can just attach the Asset Catalog to multiple targets. This is the case of having different targets with Assets of the same name but different images.

Comment: Fantastic answer, works as expected. I can keep the original assets with all the shared images, and then specific assets for each target with specific changes for each one.